# Elasticsearch: Node suddenly stops working with no shards available exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a single node elk installation which was working fine up until I discovered that `kibana` was unable to connect to `elasticsearch`.

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-12-28 14:21:33 EET; 5min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 1193 (java)
    Tasks: 87
   Memory: 3.0G
      CPU: 5min 39.675s
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           ├─1193 /usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=
           └─1548 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller
```

but here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pkaramol/cf7320a3d3973e5a39f77b75d683ebcd) with the exceptions;

for some weird reason after a restart the node seems to recover.

How can this behavior be explained?

Comment: Can you successfully run any requests against Elasticsearch? Like maybe `localhost:9200/_cat/nodes`?

Comment: Looks like the node with ELK installed experienced a crash and all shards have been unassigned. The shards re-assigned once the node was healthy again most likely fixed by the restart. Check in the logs if you see errors concerning ELK crash